# Arithmetical sequence that needs to be solved without using arrays

Tags: java, loops, sequences

I have this assignment in my Introduction to CompSci class. Our professor says the code is easy to do, we just need to solve the assignment on paper with math. Here is the assignment (NOTE: We mustn't use arrays or any kind of similar stuff, we can only use loops and if):

> For the elements of a sequence X<sub>0</sub>, X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>,...,X<sub>n</sub> it stands that X<sub>0</sub>=5, X<sub>1</sub>=-1,..., X<sub>n+2</sub>+2X<sub>n+1</sub>+X<sub>n</sub>=0. We need to write a program that scans the value of `k` and prints out X<sub>k</sub>.

For max points we need to make X<sub>1</sub>=A, X<sub>2</sub>=B where `A` and `B` are scanned from keyboard.

Here is my try, I know how to print X<sub>k</sub> but I don't know what to print (Since this is Java I will only copy the content of my main):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int k=in.nextInt();

int a = 5;
int b = -1;
for(i=3;i<=k;i++)
{

}
```

I know this is probably demeaning for anybody here to do, but I'm really stuck and I don't know how to solve this one. I have examples of different types of similar assignments that i solved easy but this part X<sub>n+2</sub>+2X<sub>n+1</sub>+X<sub>n</sub>=0 bugs me.

Comment: This site is NOT for homework.

Comment: Yes. I probably should have formatted that better by putting it in subscript.

Answer (score 0):

So, the rule is that

> X<sub>n+2</sub> + 2 * X<sub>n+1</sub> + X<sub>n</sub> = 0

So the value of X<sub>n+2</sub> is

> X<sub>n+2</sub> = 0 - 2 * X<sub>n+1</sub> - X<sub>n</sub>

Since you know X<sub>0</sub> and X<sub>1</sub>, you can compute X<sub>2</sub> using that rule. Since you now know X<sub>2</sub> and X<sub>1</sub>, you can compute X<sub>3</sub> using that rule. Since you now know X<sub>3</sub> and X<sub>2</sub>, you can compute X<sub>4</sub> using that rule. And you can continue until you know X<sub>k</sub>.

The implementation is left as an exercise. The important trick is that all you need to remember (i.e. store in two variables `a` and `b`, for example), are the two previous values of X<sub>n+1</sub> and X<sub>n</sub>, to be able to compute X<sub>n+2</sub>.

Comment: I think i get whay you're saying to me. So I just need to solve equation and use that as differential between two elements. Can you tell me is this right solution:
    `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n=in.nextInt();
  
  int a = 5;
  int b = -1;
  int x=0;
  for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
  {
  
   x=2*(b*a);
   a=b;
   b=x;
   
  }
  System.out.println(x);`

Comment: No, since `Xn+2 = 0 - 2 * Xn+1 - Xn`. What you have implemented is `Xn+2 = 2 * Xn-1 * Xn-2`. This is simple math.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks for the edit. Much more readable this way. The OP does update a and b at each iteration.

Comment: I updated it to go `Xn+2 = 0 - 2 * Xn+1 - Xn`. It gives me the same result, is the assignment correct now?

Comment: Test it. Execute your algorithm for k = 0, k = 1, k = 2, ... k = 5. Verify that the rule given in the assignment is verified for every value of k.

Comment: I verified it and it works for everything but the k=0 and k=1. That's because I start my loop from 2, because X0 and X1 are given I tought I should start counting elements from 3rd element.

Comment: Just implement two specific cases for k = 0 and k = 1.

Answer (score 0):

As was already stated

> X<sub>n+2</sub> = 0 - 2 * X<sub>n+1</sub> - X<sub>n</sub>

now, substitute

> n = k - 2

and you get

> X<sub>k</sub> = - 2 * X<sub>k-1</sub> - X<sub>k-2</sub>

now, write a function that returns X<sub>k</sub>

```java
int x(int k) {
   return -2 * x(k - 1) - x(k - 2);
}
```

Now this is obviously an infinite recursion, so fix it by introducing known values and limits:

```java
int x(int k) {
   if (k < 0) throw new runtimeException();
   if (k == 0) return 5;
   if (k == 1) return -1;
   return -2 * x(k - 1) - x(k - 2);
}
```

This is not an efficient solution, just an exercise.